# How to store a select query result ( one result ) to a variable using executescalar() ? ( ASP.NET )

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

i have to store a select query result in a variable .i'm new in asp.net . i used executescalar but it doesn't work. i try many times but i failed here my last try :

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection())
{
    var connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connections"].ToString();
    sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connetionString;
    string sql = "Select sum((prime_comptant+10)*0.12) from mvt_garantie_quittance where numero_quittance='" + numQuittance + "'";
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlConnection);
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(dataset);
    string result = dataset.Tables[0].ToString();
}
```

Can you fix the code to me? i have to store the result in a variable

Comment: Try to detail your problem more, what doesn't work ? Is there any exception thrown ? is your dataset null ?

Comment: the result variable is null . is the code correct ?

Comment: Also learn what a dataset is. What you are surely missing is``string  result = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();``

Comment: i correct it but the result variable is still null :(

Comment: Do your request return something when  you execute it in your sql client?

Comment: Sir the query works fine on sql queries .No sir i just wanna the sum of 'prime_comptant' in a variable without return

Comment: Are you sure there is a record with numero_quittance = numQuittance in your mvt_garantie_quittance table and that the prime_comptant field is not null ? Witch DBMS are you using ?

Comment: Sir there is a record with numero_quittance=numQuittance in mvt_garantie_quittance table and prime_comptant is not null . i checkd it

Comment: It doesn't make sense, is the result null or "null" ? null.ToString() should throw a NullReferenceException.

Comment: the result in null .there is no NullReferenceException . it doesn't give me any errors

Comment: Can you please change the code for me using executescalar() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string sql = "Select sum((prime_comptant+10)*0.12) from mvt_garantie_quittance where numero_quittance='" + numQuittance + "'";

var connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connections"].ToString();

string result = null;

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    conn.Open();
    result = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank u Sir . but there is an error here : sqlConnection.ConnectionString = connetionString;

Comment: i resolved it . but sorry sir for making you tired of me . the result is still null . :( :/

Comment: Which DBMS do you use ? Oracle ? mySQL ? SQL server ?

Comment: i use sql Server

Comment: The code is fine, try running the query directly on server. Seems no rows qualify.

Comment: @TAnveer Badar : i executed so many time on sql server and it works

Comment: Change your query to ``Select ISNULL(sum((ISNULL(prime_comptant,0)+10)*0.12),0) as sommePrimeComptant from ...``

Comment: @B.Lec : the same problem persists :( the result is null ) ,

Comment: @OussamaHsini Did you find the reason why it was null ?

Comment: Hi lec i used an update query with multiple fields and tables to get my update . thanks for helping me but executescalar didn't work also Oledbcommand didn't work . so i think differently and make all things in update query . i did need the variable to stock informations to use it later in update query . but when we failed i switch to the update query directly . thank u a lot and i marked your reply as a solution because the code is fine